# How to install lsd_slam on my ROS?

Tags: ros-kinetic, build, 3d-slam, build-package, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to create an autonomous drone. For this task, I want to employ  the monocular SLAM method. After reading a few papers and having trawled forums on the internet, I have decided to use [LSD_SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam). Now I have built my **ROS Kinetic** from source on my **Raspberry Pi** with **Raspbian Lite**. To install a new package I will have to first invoke the command:

```
rosinstall_generator ros_comm <your_extra_packages> --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
```

For this I replaced the `<your_extra_packages>` with just `lsd_slam`. However, it returns saying:

```
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: lsd_slam
```

How am I supposed to install `lsd_slam` onto my *ROS* now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250822/how-to-install-lsd_slam-on-my-ros?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means lsd_slam has not been officially released, which means you'll have to build it from source.

They have installation instructions on their github repository; have you tried following them?

They're still using an outdated build system (rosbuild), so you'll have to learn about how to set up a rosbuild workspace. This [rosbuild with catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) tutorial is pretty good, and despite saying it applies to ROS Groovy, it actually applies to Groovy and all newer versions of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-29**:
I don't want to use rosbuild as of now, and therefore will defer to a different package that is released for catkin.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-13**:
Will lsd_slam be available on Ubuntu MATE? I hope I wouldn't have to build from source on Ubuntu MATE too?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-13**:
Unreleased means unreleased. There are no binaries of any kind. You should still be able to install the dependencies through apt (binaries) and then build only lsd_slam in your workspace.